# Text only is distorted in Ubuntu 13.10 with Intel graphics

Tags: fonts

Letters occasionally display distorted in browsers, file managers, terminals, etc. Images are unaffected.

I have an Intel Pentium Dual Core CPU with integrated graphics, and an SSD. I should also mention that when I highlight the text it becomes legible.

[image]

as you can see in the line "as I'm starting this because there is another thread" Thread is distorted.  I have tried to option suggestion provided by you guys. I also updated my Intel Graphics driver.  Do you think it could have something to do with the Samsung SSD?  Remember although this happened in the browser, it happens everywhere other than the launcher.

Comment: Could you provide a picture? Highlight some of the text and some of it not to see the diference

Comment: It's been "discussed" here: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2194616. Toz pointed out that "the default acceleration method was changed from uxa to sna" and this affects systems with Intel Graphic cards in 13.10 (and even 14.04).

Comment: @Rat2000 some users can take screenshots of the deformed text; for others, including myself, even pressing printscreen (to take the screenshot) remove the deformation!